# Swapping tuples of different types in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I'm trying to write a simple function that will swap a (Int, String) tuple in Scala. I've tried a number of things and I keep getting compiler errors, for example:

```
def swap (p:(Int,String)) : (String,Int) = {
      var s = p._1
      var t = p._2
      var u = (p._2, p.1)
}

[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: (String, Int)
[error]     }
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
```

Why does it keep saying it finds a "Unit" type? I've tried different variations, and even using the "swap" function built into Scala, but I keep getting these kinds of errors stating that my return type isn't (String, Int). Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your code has 2 problems: a missing underscore `_` and you have 3 assignments but you don't return any values.

Comment: Woops on the underscore, I wasn't running it like that, I just put that in here as my example. Regarding the return - I thought Scala it would return what my last assignment is?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem: the last expression in your method is an assignment, and an assignment has no value, so that is what is being returned: a value that denotes the absence of a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
def swap(p: (Int,String)): (String,Int) = (p._2, p._1)
```

And to make it work on any tuple (of size 2):

```
def swap[A,B](p: (A,B)): (B,A) = (p._2, p._1)
```

In Scala, the last expression in a function is the returned value. It also supports an explicit return expression, that would be like this:

```
def swap(p: (Int,String)): (String,Int) = { 
  return (p._2, p._1)
}
```

or more like what you intended:

```
def swap(p: (Int,String)): (String,Int) = { 
  val result = (p._2, p._1)
  return result
}
```

Keep in mind this explicit return syntax is not recommended.

Because Scala is a functional language, everything is an expression. Expressions are anything you can evaluate and get back a resulting value, which, being a value, has a type.

Even things that you would think more like "statements", like `println("a")` or `var a = 1` are expressions. When evaluated, they return a meaningless/empty value, that is of type `Unit`. Therefore, your function returns the last statement, that is a variable assignment, which has a value of type `Unit`.

Comment: oh wow, really that easy. So my issue was that I assigned a var to my (p._2, p.1). Why does that make it fail?

Comment: The return value of a method is the value of the last expression inside the method. Your last expression is an assignment, but assignments *have no value*. In fact, in a language which distinguishes between expressions and statements, an assignment would be a statement. Scala doesn't have statements, but it has a value that denotes the absence of a value `()` and a corresponding type `Unit`, which is kinda-sorta similar to the not-really-a-type-pseudo-type `void` in C-like languages, which is the not-really-a-type-pseudo-type of statements.

Answer (score 4):

The return value of a method (or more generally, the value of *any* block) is the value of the last expression inside the block. The last expression in your block is

```
var u = (p._2, p.1)
```

The value of an assignment is `()` (which is the singleton value of the `Unit` type): an assignment is a side-effect, it doesn't *have* a value, and `()` is the value (and `Unit` the type) which denotes the absence of a value (think "`void`" if you are familiar with C, C++, D, Objective-C, Objective-C++, Java, or C♯); ergo, your method returns `()`, which is of type `Unit`.

Here's a more Scala-ish way to write your method:

```
def swap[A, B](p: (A, B)) = (p._2, p._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it using pattern matching and function literal:

```
def swap[X,Y]: ((X,Y)) => ((Y,X)) = { case (x, y) => (y, x) }
```